# Qt QOpenGLFunction_4_5_Compatibility vs QOpenGLExtraFunctions

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, qt-creator, qtopengl

i am currently using QOpenGLFunction_4_5_Compability in my GLWidget. Because QOpenGLFunctions doesn't contains glLoadIdentity, glOrtho, glGenBuffers, glBindBuffer and so on.

> Why some people using QOpenGLFunctions instead of QOpenGLFunction_4_5_Compability? What is the thing that makes QOpenGLFunctions special?
>
> Which one i should use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtgui-module.html

QOpenglFunctions is for GLES 2.0. So, if you use 4.5, then you may use functions that are not available in GLES.

Decide a minimum GL version that your program will require from the users, and then use the profile with this version.